# Effect of more tables on database efficiency SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently attempting to create a `chat program` aimed for **1000-1500** users. I was wondering if i should create a **separate table** for each `user`, as in a table for each users friends, message or should  just create one include all table and store everything there, as in which solution would be more `efficient`? I believe having `multiple` tables for each users personal details would be `more efficient` so that most queries i run are run on tables with small amount of data.

Could anyone tell me if i am wrong?

Comment: Why pre-maturely optimize? 1000-1500 users doesn't sound like much. Think instead of how hard it might be to maintain a set of tables for each user. How would you roll out changes/run queries against all those users?

Comment: If the program were aimed at a million users, you'd end up with 1000000 * 3+ = 3000000+ *tables*. Doesn't really sound like a good idea to me.

Comment: In general, you don't want to even _think_ about generating "a SQL table per _x_" where _x_ is anything that can grow without bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very wrong. Ideal way should be to have one single table for users. Even for companies like ebay where there are millions of users; the way those users are distributed are like all users starting with A in a single table ... As @Matt mentioned we cannot create tables where x is not a bounded number.

Along with that table you can have a table Messages which will have a column UserName which will be a foreign key pointing to your user table.

Cleanest possible solution can be a bit tricky for maintaining friends list. A workaround solution can be to have a column in User table which will have comma separated ids of Friends ( which are again users in same table ). If you do not want any limits on friends list:  You could just create another table Friends having two columns userid, friendId. Both these columns will be foreign keys on User table. Now, query will be simple `select * form Friends where userid=<user>` .  This table might be huge; but that is where index comes into picture. You can create an index on userid column and query results will be super fast even with lots of records.

Comment: I dont really have a limit on the number of freinds a user can have. The way i have currently laid out the tables is a table per user containing his freinds. I did this mainly because for each user i need to query his freinds every 5 seconds and i thought a query in a large table to find a small amount of data may be less efficient then querying a tabe with a small amount of data to find it

Comment: That is where index comes into picture. You can create an index on that column and query results will be super fast even with lots of records.

Comment: Use the join table, add indexes and caching as necessary. Keeping friends ids as a comma-separated list is brittle and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bad approach to set a table for each user, you can exactly save a text file for each user, you dont need a database for that, the idea of using a ddatabase is build the relations between the entities, therefor you have the primary/foreign keys, in general you need a table for each entity, sometimes 3 tables for 2 entities depending on the Cardinality. In your would be normal to have for example a user table, messages table, messageUser table and freinds or contacts table etc, where the freinds one would store the UserIds whos connected as freinds , and the messages one the messageId<->UserId tuple which matches the messages to the user and so on.